# How to pass data from AntD table to another component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I'm using AntD to create my react app. So I want to pass data from the table(parent) to another component(child). This is parent ClassTheoryDataTable.jsx,

```
    import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
    
    import { Table, Input, InputNumber, Popconfirm, Form, Typography, Button } from 'antd';
    import ClassTheoryDetails from './ClassTheoryDetails';
    
    export default function ClassTheoryDataTable() {
        
    
        const dataSource = [
            {
                key: '1',
                date: '18.03.2021',
                subject: 'Revision',
                inst: 'HASHEL',
                edit: 'edit',
                delete: 'delete'
            },
            {
                key: '2',
                date: '17.03.2021',
                subject: 'Thrust Augmentation',
                inst: 'HASHEL',
                edit: 'edit',
                delete: 'delete'
            },
            {
                key: '3',
                date: '16.03.2021',
                subject: 'Lubrication, APU and Performance',
                inst: 'HASHEL',
                edit: 'edit',
                delete: 'delete'
            },
            {
                key: '4',
                date: '15.03.2021',
                subject: 'Enine starting & Ignition systems',
                inst: 'HASHEL',
                edit: 'edit',
                delete: 'delete'
            },
            {
                key: '5',
                date: '14.03.2021',
                subject: 'Auxiliary GearBox, Reverse Thrust & Fuels',
                inst: 'HASHEL',
                edit: 'edit',
                delete: 'delete'
            }
        ];
    
    
        const columns = [
            {
                title: 'Date',
                dataIndex: 'date',
                key: 'date',
                render: date => {
                    return <a onClick={showDetails(date)}>{date}</a>
                },
                editable: true
            },
            {
                title: 'Subject',
                dataIndex: 'subject',
                key: 'subject',
                editable: true
            },
            {
                title: 'Inst.',
                dataIndex: 'inst',
                key: 'inst',
                editable: true
            },
            {
                title: '',
                dataIndex: 'edit',
                key: 'edit',
                render: edit => {
                    return <a>{edit}</a>
                }
            },
            {
                title: '',
                dataIndex: 'delete',
                key: 'delete',
                render: delet => {
                    return <a>{delet}</a>
                }
            }
        ];
    
        const showDetails = (date) => {
           console.log({date});
        }
    
    
        return (
            <>
                <Table columns={columns} dataSource={dataSource} bordered />
                
            </>
        );
    }
```

when I click the date in table, then it need to pass the date and subject properties to the ClassTheoryDetails.jsx (child) and use in that component.

```
import { Button, Dropdown, Menu, Table, Tag, Space } from 'antd';
import React from 'react';
import { VerticalAlignBottomOutlined, CloseOutlined, EditOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';
import './ClassTheoryDetails.css';

const { Column, ColumnGroup } = Table;

export default function ClassTheoryDetails(props) {

    const menu = (
        <Menu >
            <Menu.Item key="1">docx</Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item key="2">pdf</Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item key="3">xml</Menu.Item>
        </Menu>
    );

    const data = [
        {
            key: '1',
            student: 'Isha - Mariyam Isha Shareef',
            studentComment: ''
        },
        {
            key: '2',
            student: 'Nasru - Ibrahim Nasru Ali',
            studentComment: ''
        },
        {
            key: '3',
            student: 'Sanyaan - Ahmen Sanyaan Shameel',
            studentComment: ''
        },
        {
            key: '4',
            student: 'Zareef - Mohamed Dhaisam Zareef',
            studentComment: ''
        }
    ];

    return (
        <>
            <div>
                <h1>Powerplant</h1>
                <p style={{opacity:0.5}}>18.03.2021 12:00 - 14:00</p>
                <Dropdown overlay={menu} trigger={["click"]}>
                    <Button><VerticalAlignBottomOutlined />Export as</Button>
                </Dropdown>
            </div><hr/>
            <div>
                <h3>Instructor</h3>
                <p>HASHEL - Hashel Fernando</p>
                <h3>Subject</h3>
                <p>Revision</p>
                <h3>Comment</h3>
                <p style={{fontStyle:'italic'}}>There is no comment</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <Table dataSource={data} bordered={true} className="table">
                    <ColumnGroup  title="Class theory" fontSize="20px" align="left">
                        <Column title="Student" dataIndex="student" key="student" />
                        <Column title="Student comment" dataIndex="studentComment" key="studentComment" />
                    </ColumnGroup>
                </Table>
            </div>
            <Space>
                <Button style={{borderRadius:"6px"}}><EditOutlined />Edit</Button>
                <Button style={{borderRadius:"6px", color:"white", backgroundColor:"red"}}><CloseOutlined />Delete</Button>
            </Space>

        </>
    );
}
```

I tried props but it didn't work. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use onRow property to provide onClick handler, save row data to state and provide to child component as props

```
 const [state, useState] = useState({})

 <Table
   // Record is a row data { data, subject, ... }
   onRow={(record) => {
     return {
       onClick: event => {
         // save row data to state
         setState(record)
       }, // click row
     };
   }}
 />

 // provide row data to child component
 <ClassTheoryDetails {...state} />
```